# Trouble with jQuery keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

The page reloads instead of calling the click function, but if I insert a query string `?#` after the .html extension, it works. Tested in chrome

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#search_btn').click(function () {
                alert("searching");
                // search functions

            });

            $("#search").keyup(function (event) {
                if (event.which == 13) {
                    alert("enter key pressed");
                    $("#search_btn").click();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
       <input type="text" id="search" />
       <button class="btn" type="button" id="search_btn">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which html extension are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent specific FORM to be submitted, using e.g:

```
$('form:has(#search)').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Nice! It took me some searching myself before I came up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Make this change to your code

```
$('#search_btn').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("searching");
     // search functions
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the event as a parameter of your `click()` function, then prevent the default handler of that event using `event.preventDefault()`so it won't redirect.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#search_btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("searching");
        // search functions

      });

      $("#search").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
          alert("enter key pressed");
          $("#search_btn").click();
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search" />
  <button class="btn" type="button" id="search_btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT:** If that does not do the trick, prevent the form from submitting by adding:

```
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

You can replace `form` with an ID given to the form.

Comment: But there is no default behaviour for button of type button  http://jsfiddle.net/sum0bs1q/

Comment: Oh, woops. Thanks @A.Wolff, then it's the form submitting. I'll edit my answer.